# How to set an environment variable in emacs shell (eshell)?

Tags: emacs, environment-variables, eshell

I cannot seem to find this anywhere. A lot of times I run commands with an environment variable set like:

```
export BLA=foo && ./somebinary
```

How do i do this in `eshell`? I think the command is called `set` but i'm not sure how to use it, what would be the above equivalent in `eshell`?

Comment: You are looking for `setenv`

Comment: What about eshell "cd"-ed into a remote directory via tramp?

Comment: To answer my own question - it depend on the transport methods used in tramp - I have been using "scpx" which uses a simple shell and thus not preserving the environment variables that I have setup. Changing it back to "scp" (or "ssh") worked! ;)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
~ $ (setenv "XYZ" "abc")
abc
~ $ ./e.sh
abc
~ $ cat e.sh
echo $XYZ
~ $ (setenv "XYZ" "abc")
abc
~ $ ./e.sh
abc
```

Comment: Why not just `setenv XYZ abc`?

Comment: I don't remember :(. Maybe I was trying to make it more lisp like, for example I can use the function call in `init.el`, `\*scratch\*` buffer, or `eshell`.

Answer (score 3):

I set variables in my bash profile like so:

```
export WORK_DIR=/Users/me/Documents/some/dir
```

Then in .emacs I put this:

```
(let ((work_dir (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bash_profile; echo -n $WORK_DIR")))
(setenv "WORK_DIR" work_dir))
```